# Is $Emb_E(K,L)$=$Hom(K,L)$ for field extensions?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E \subset K$, $E \subset L$ be field extensions. We denote by $Hom(K,L)$ the set of homomorphisms from $K$ to $L$, and by $Emb_E(K,L)$ the set of homomorphisms from $K$ to $L$ which restrict to identity on $E$.

Let $E$ be the prime subfield of both $K$ and $L$.
Is $Emb_E(K,L)$=$Hom(K,L)$?

**Remark:** The left-in-right inclusion is trivial; I am asking if every homomorphism fixes the prime subfield $E$.

**Idea for proof:** Any homomorphism must fix 1, hence must fix the prime subfield. Is this correct?

(I am aware there are some similar questions but typically the statements only involve $E=\mathbb{Q}$ or $K$=$L$. I am trying to generalize these into one result, using the same proof.)